# Type-safe navigationHandler with React-Navigation

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have an issue with Typescript and React Navigation for my React Native app.
I've got the following setup in my project, which gives me awesome help and autocompletion when using e.g. `navigation.push()`.

Types

```
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';

export type RootStackParamList = {
    Home: undefined;
    Content: undefined;
    List: undefined;
};

export type StackNavigationProps = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>;
```

Usage

```
const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProps>();
```

However, I've created a navigation handler function that takes a parameter that gets fed to `navigation.push`. It works fine as long as the type of the parameter is of type `any`.

```
const navigationHandler = useCallback((targetScreen) => {
    navigation.push(targetScreen);
}, [navigation]);
```

But I am not satisfied with the `any` type and would prefer that `targetScreen` could in fact just be one of the screens that were declared in my `RootStackParamList` type. I have tried in countless ways to satisfy the `push` method of the navigation object but I'm stuck.

The following attempt has been the most successful but is yet not working exactly as it should. It does give me autocompletion on available screens, but the `push` is still unhappy.

Type:

```
export type NavigationScreen<T extends RootStackParamList> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K;
}[keyof T];
```

Usage:

```
const navigationHandler = useCallback(
    <T extends RootStackParamList>(targetScreen: NavigationScreen<T>) => {
        navigation.push(targetScreen);
},[navigation]);
```

Hovering the error I get prompted with the following:

> (parameter) targetScreen: { [K in keyof T]: K; }[keyof T] Argument of
>   type '[{ [K in keyof T]: K; }[keyof T]]' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '["Home" | "Content" | "List"] | ["Home" | "Content"
>   | "List", undefined]'.   Type '[{ [K in keyof T]: K; }[keyof T]]' is
>   not assignable to type '["Home" | "Content" | "List"]'.
>       Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type '"Home" | "Content" | "List"'.
>         Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type '"Home" | "Content" | "List"'.
>           Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"Home" | "Content" | "List"'.
>             Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type '"List"'.
>               Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type '"List"'.
>                 Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"List"'.

How to get this working?

Comment: I don't have a good environment to reproduce your issue at the moment, but most probably what you are looking for is `targetScreen: keyof RootStackParamList`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're just interested in using the name of the screen for your `navigationHandler` function but not the params, you can do as @artcorpse suggested in his comment to your question and use `keyof RootStackParamList`:

```js
const navigationHandler = useCallback(
    (targetScreen: keyof RootStackParamList) => {
        navigation.push(targetScreen);
    },
    [navigation]
);
```

If, on the other hand, you want to allow for params, you've got two options:

#### Option A: Generic function

```js
const navigationHandler = useCallback(
    <T extends keyof RootStackParamList>(
        targetScreen: T,
        targetScreenParams?: RootStackParamList[T]
    ) => {
        navigation.push(
            targetScreen as keyof RootStackParamList,
            targetScreenParams
        );
    },
    [navigation]
);
```

The upside of this option is that route parameter object shapes are checked against the corresponding routes as defined in the `RootStackParamList` type. For example,

```js
type RootStackParamList = {
    Default: undefined,
    Home: {a: 'a'};
    Profile: { userId: string };
};

navigationHandler('Home', {a: 'a'}); //OK
navigationHandler('Home', {userId: 'a'}); //ERROR
```

#### Option B: Reversing already existing types

```js
const navigationHandler2 = useCallback(
    (
        targetScreen: Parameters<typeof navigation.push>[0],
        targetScreenParams?: Parameters<typeof navigation.push>[1]
    ) => {
        navigation.push(targetScreen, targetScreenParams);
    },
    [navigation]
);
```

This option takes the existing types you've defined and attempts to extract them from the `navigation.push` method. The downside here is that you won't get the above mentioned check regarding routes and their corresponding parameter object shapes.

#### Sources:

- [API documentation for navigation.push](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/)
- [Typescript recommendations for react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#annotating-usenavigation)

Comment: Thanks for such a brilliant answer. I am in the process of learning TypeScript and yet not too familiar with it - but I find this solution both elegant and straight forward. There you go, bounty of 100 + correct answer + upvote are all yours.

Comment: can you explain more on option A> Generic function
const navigationHandler
How to use it?